# How do I edit this code so that [‘7005000’] is printed twice

Tags: python, function

This is the function I have:

```
def some_func(some_list):
  some_list.append('567')
  return some_list

l = ['7005000']
print(l)
print(some_func(l))
print(l)
```

Comment: Where do you want to have it twice? And the whole list? Just the first element? The question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mutate the passed `list` object in your function, but return a new one:

```
def some_func(some_list):
    return some_list + ['567']
```